# How tho solve the permission denied problem in NDK code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, fopen, permission-denied

I want to read a bmp file in ndk code, but it always failed.and the error code showed the permission denied. how to solve this problem?

The IDE is Android Studio 3.1.2,but I think it is nothing to do with IDE. The device is hikey960 with Android 9 API28. 
I have referenced some similay issues and added the user-permission in Manifest.xml and specify the absolute path, but it still doesn't work! But if I build it as a executalbe file and push to /data/ and give a full permission, it works normally!

here is the ndk code:

```
FILE *fpbmp = fopen (imagefile, "r+");

if (fpbmp == NULL) {
    LOGD ("open file failed!");
    LOGD("code %s \n", strerror(errno));

}
```

and the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wangzh.normaltest">
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

....

The logcat shows that the error code means permission denied:

```
/sdcard/DCIM/1_1.bmp 
open file failed!
code Permission denied
```

Could someone give some advices? Anything will be appreciated!

Comment: Both `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are regarded as _dangerous_ permissions. That is, declaring them in your manifest is not sufficient; you also need to [request the user to grant your app these permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me a so important thing that I ignored before. Now I added the runtime permissions request code, but it still doesn't work. I really have no idea about it!

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the reason!
the permission of the bmp file in /sdcard/DCIM/ is -rw-rw----. It can't be changed even though run the chmod command and set permission in AndroidManifest.xml and run-time.
So I mv file to /data/ and chmod 777 thefile. then it  work well and doesn't need permission in AndroidManifest.xml or run-time permission.

Answer (score 0):

on the console, input the below command:

```
su   
setenforce  0
```

You can use the below command to check if the command is inputed before.

```
getenforce
```

if it return "Permissive", it is ok.
I use android 11, cpp code is at hidl interface. With this method, it is solved.  fopen/fwrite/fread work well.